# How to Add a button to the Gxt HtmlEditor

Tags: gxt, html-editor

Is somebody knows a way of adding a button to the `Toolbar` of the `HtmlEditor` without doing with `JSNI`

Answer (score 0):

use simple html input code in your string and set as inner html

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
htmlEditor.setValue("<br/><button type='button'>Click Me!</button>");
```